# Does an UMVUE always exist?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

Let $\Psi= \{f_\theta: \theta \in \Theta\}$ be a statistical model. Define $\Upsilon= \{T: E[T]= g(\theta)\}$ - i.e., the class of unbiased estimator of $g(\theta)$. Basically, I have two doubts:

1. Does an UMVUE always exist? Thanks to Rao-Blackwell theorem, we can improve the "goodness" of an unbiased estimator using a sufficient statistic, i.e. $T\mid U$ where $T$ is our unbiased estimator and $U$ our sufficient statistic. Moreover, thanks to Lehmann–Scheffé theorem, I have that if $U$ is also complete, then $T^*= E[T\mid U]$ is UMVUE. My dilemma here is that I wrote on my notes that it is not true that an UMVUE for $g(\theta)$ always exist, but I cannot understand how it is possible. If UMVUE does not always exist, it implies that a complete statistic does not always exist or an unbiased estimator of $g(\theta)$ that is function of the complete statistic does not always exist. If this is true, could you provide me a counterexample- i.e. an example where an UMVUE does not exist?
2. Suppose that $T$ is an efficient estimator for $g(\theta)$ - i.e. $V(T)$= Cramér-Rao lower bound. I already know that if $T$ is efficient for $g(\theta)$, then $a+bT$ is efficient for $a+bg(\theta)$ but for no other transformation. But is $g(T)$ always UMVUE for a $g(g(\theta)) \,\forall g$- i.e. if $T$ is an efficient estimator of $g(\theta)$, a transformation of $T$ is always UMVUE for a transformation of $g(\theta)$ ?

Comment: Obviously UMVUE does not exist when an unbiased estimator does not exist. But even when unbiased estimator exists, there is a result which roughly says that an unbiased estimator is UMVUE iff it is uncorrelated with every unbiased estimator of zero. As an example consider a sample of size $n$ (can take $n=1$ also) from $U(\theta,\theta+1)$ where you are to estimate $\theta$.

Comment: Look at the example with non-complete sufficient statistic https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4960505/

Comment: @StubbornAtom I already know that T is UMVUE iff it is uncorrelated with all unbiased est of zero but it seems to me too harsh to prove that. Thanks for the example. What about point 2?

Comment: Even if $T$ is just an unbiased estimator of $\theta$, it does not imply $f(T)$ is unbiased for $f(\theta)$. Also, it is possible for UMVUE to exist without its variance attaining the CR lower bound.

Answer (score 4):

> To answer your first question, even if an unbiased estimator exists it does not guarantee that a UMVUE exists.

Consider a single observation $X$ having the uniform distribution on $(\theta,\theta+1)$ and suppose we have to estimate $g(\theta)$ for some function $g$.

So $X$ is minimal sufficient for $\theta$. As for completeness of $X$, notice that $$E_{\theta}[\sin (2\pi X)]=\int_{\theta}^{\theta+1}\sin (2\pi x)\,dx=0\quad,\,\forall\,\theta\in\mathbb R$$

However $\sin (2\pi X)$ is not almost surely $0$, so that $X$ is not a complete statistic.

In fact a complete sufficient statistic does not exist for this model.

*To see whether UMVUE of $g(\theta)$ actually exists or not, recall the [necessary-sufficient condition](http://pages.stat.wisc.edu/~doksum/STAT709/n709-31.pdf) for an unbiased estimator (with finite second moment) to be the UMVUE which says that the unbiased estimator has to be uncorrelated with every unbiased estimator of zero.*

If possible, suppose $T$ is UMVUE of $g(\theta)$. Let $\mathcal U_0$ be the class of all unbiased estimators of zero.

Clearly for every $H\in \mathcal U_0$,

$$\int_{\theta}^{\theta+1}H(x)\,dx=0\quad,\,\forall\,\theta\in\mathbb R$$

Differentiating both sides of the last equation with respect to $\theta$ gives

$$H(\theta+1)=H(\theta)\quad,\,\text{a.e.}\tag{1}$$

As $T$ is UMVUE, $E_{\theta}(TH)=0$ for all $\theta$ and for all $H\in \mathcal U_0$. In other words, $TH\in \mathcal U_0$ whenever $H\in \mathcal U_0$. So analogous to $(1)$ we have

$$T(\theta+1)H(\theta+1)=T(\theta)H(\theta)\quad,\,\text{a.e.}\tag{2}$$

And $(1)$ implies $$T(\theta)=T(\theta+1)\quad,\,\text{a.e.}\tag{3}$$

Again as $T$ is unbiased for $\theta$, $$\int_{\theta}^{\theta+1} T(x)\,dx=g(\theta)\quad,\,\forall\,\theta\in\mathbb R $$

Differentiating both sides wrt $\theta$ and equation $(3)$ yields

$$g'(\theta)=T(\theta+1)-T(\theta)=0\quad,\,\text{a.e.}$$

This shows that $g(\theta)$ does not admit a UMVUE for any non-constant $g$.

So if you take $g(\theta)=\theta$, then $T=X-\frac12$ is unbiased for $\theta$ but $T$ is not UMVUE.

---

As for the second question, even if $T$ is just an unbiased estimator (efficient or not) of $\theta$, it *does not* mean $g(T)$ is unbiased (forget UMVUE) for $g(\theta)$ for an arbitrary nonlinear function $g$.

Among several possible examples, consider i.i.d observations $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ having an exponential distribution with mean $\theta$. Then it is easy to verify that the sample mean $\overline X$ is an efficient estimator (and UMVUE) of $\theta$ but $\overline X^2$ is not UMVUE of $\theta^2$.